# How to rename my Android app?

Tags: android, eclipse

I wish to rename my android app and package name. I have successfully done the latter via refactoring, but I'm having trouble with the former.

I have renamed the Java project, and I've also edited strings.xml to reflect the new app_name. However, while the new app name is reflected in my main activity as well as in the app drawer/home screen, when I try to view the app on the device in application manager, the old app name is still displayed.

How do I update that?

Comment: I'd do a grep on the project and see if you've missed somewhere. The manifest is another place to check.

Comment: You can use Android Tools-> Rename Application Package ->and then update all dependecies and after that you have to manually change src packages name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be the temporary issue. If you uninstall and re-install the application I think it will be resolved. And when users update from the Play Store it should be updated as well.

The application name is received from the `android:label` value in the `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Comment: Thanks, uninstalling and reinstalling didn't work, but it updated after I rebooted the device.

Comment: I think the behavior is different in different phones. Some phone can display the new app name right away, but some needs reboot.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `Application Name` into `android:label` attribute of `<application>` tag in `manifest.xml` file

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
     >...</application>
```

And also change the `Package` into `manifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="New Package Name"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >....</manifest>
```

And after this built your project again see here for more info:http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html